# ExtJS/Sencha - Add button to DateField popup, to clear date

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a DateField:

```
  editor : new Ext.form.DateField({ /*Ext.ux.form.Custom*/
      allowBlank: true,
      format: 'm/d/Y',
      width : 120,
      enableKeyEvents: true,
      listeners: {
              'keydown' : function (field_, e_  )  {
                field_.onTriggerClick();
                e_.stopEvent();
                return false;
          },
              'focus' : function (field_  )  {
                field_.onTriggerClick();
                e_.stopEvent();
                return false;
          }
      }
  })
```

Editing of this field is disabled. On any edit, it shows popup, so any clear of date is impossible. Is there a way to add to popup something like button Today, but meaning Clear, after which date in this field will be resetted to 00.00.00?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated*

Its made  - here is code:
http://publikz.com/?p=1223

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    onTriggerClick: function() {
        Ext.form.DateField.prototype.onTriggerClick.apply(this, arguments);
        var btn = new Ext.Button({
            text: 'Clear'
        });
        btn.render(this.menu.picker.todayBtn.container);
    }
}
```

It's very dependent on implementation, but it works. And you must flag it that way it won't render another clear button every time you click the trigger.

Comment: interesting idea, but flagging it - this a problem, i was need rewrite few metdods - adding a showRest property, to make this idea live :) Here is http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?106446-ClearableDateField

Answer (score 3):

You can get reference to the [Ext.picker.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date) component (responsible for displaying the calendar popup) with DateField's [getPicker()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker-method-getPicker) method. You can then customize the text of the `Today` button with config option [todayText](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-cfg-todayText) and customize what happens when it is clicked by overriding the [selectToday()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-method-selectToday) method.

(If you want to keep the `Today` button as it is, and add another button instead, it can be done too, by extending / customizing `Ext.picker.date`, but it is a bit more complicated.)

Comment: seems i need add one more button, already try few methods ... can your answer - it is a need of editing component or of creating new one?

Answer (score 3):

```
calendar = .....  // find the calendar component 

clearDateButton = new Ext.Button({
    renderTo: calendar.el.child("td.x-date-bottom,true"),
    text: "Clear Date",
    handler: ......
})
```

Comment: This is problem for me - find it. Ext3.3.4

Comment: 3.3.1 extjs dont have it ... anyway, i rewrite methods and all is ok now. Tnx for help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is searching for a small solution in ExtJS 4 here is my suggestion:

```
Ext.picker.Date.override({
        beforeRender: function() {
            this.clearBtn = new Ext.button.Button({
                text: 'Clear',
                handler: this.clearDate,
                scope: this
            });
            this.callOverridden(arguments);
        },
        initComponent: function() {
            var fn = function(){};
            var incmp = function(values, out){
                Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(values.$comp.clearBtn.getRenderTree(), out);
                fn(values, out);
            };
            if(this.renderTpl.length === undefined){
                fn = this.renderTpl.initialConfig.renderTodayBtn;
                this.renderTpl.initialConfig.renderTodayBtn = incmp;
            } else {
                fn = this.renderTpl[this.renderTpl.length-1].renderTodayBtn;
                this.renderTpl[this.renderTpl.length-1].renderTodayBtn = incmp;
            }
            this.callOverridden(arguments);
        },
        finishRenderChildren: function () {
            this.clearBtn.finishRender();
            this.callOverridden(arguments);
        },
        clearDate: function(){
            this.fireEvent('select', this, '');
        }
    });
```

[Working ExtJS Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/186m)